# Cannot print message according to time

Tags: javascript, datetime, time, comparison, comparison-operators

I've **three** different times, two of them are in string forms (`time1` and `time2`) and one from system date `currDate`. Next step according to the one of two above times I want to print messages when the system date reaches one of them. For this I've `function callEachMinute` that calls each minute to get system time (but here in code I did not include the whole procedure). Here is the current status of the code:

**Script:**

```
function callEachMinute() {
    var currDate = new Date();
    var time_1 = '8:30';
    var time_2 = '23:00';

    timeComparison(currDate, time_1, time_2)
}

function timeComparison(currTime, time1, time2) {

    // Time 1 formatting
    var t1 = new Date();
    var parts1 = time1.split(":");
    t1.setHours(parts1[0],parts1[1]);

    // Iftor-Time formatting
    var t2 = new Date();
    var parts2 = timeI.split(":");
    t2.setHours(parts2[0],parts2[1]);

    /* Notification procedure */
    if (currTime == t1) {
        // Message for Time1
        alert("Time 1 is reached");
    }

    if (currTime == t2) {
        // Message for Time2
        alert("Time 2 is reached");
    }
}
```

**Problem:**
When the system time is reached one of times (time1 or time2) nothing happens. Any solution for this problem?

Comment: @Barmar I need to both of times: `time1` and `time2`, because I want to display at morning message and at night some other message.

Comment: But you misspelled `time2` as `timeI`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that could be problematic here.

You set up a `Date` object then want to compare it to `currTime`:

```
if (currTime == t1) {
```

unfortunatley Javascript's `==` operator when applied to objects compares two objects to see if they are references to the same object, so even if currTime and t1 contained *exactly* the same time this check would evaluate to false since they are different instances.  You *could* do this by converting to a string:

```
if (currTime.toString() == t1.toString) {
```

which would work if the string representations for each data work out the same.

However, a more straight forward approach might be to tackle this the other way around - extract the hours and minutes from currTime, build a string and compare that to your time strings.  Something like:

```
// in timecomparison function
var hrs = currTime.getHours();
var mins = currTime.getMinutes();
var now = hrs+":"+mins

// now do comparisons
if (now == time1 ) {
    ....
}
```

and so on.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. It was really minor issue, but I couldn't manage it. Now it works fine :)